# How to play media (mp3) consecutively inside public void method

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, shuffle

Example, i have public void method `shuffle`. i want when i click (onclick) menuitem, some media (mp3) inside this method play consecutively and after last media it stops to play. i want `case` positions play consecutively from `case 0` till `case 3` and after play `case 3` the mediaplayer stops to play.  i need they play automatically, like after `case 0` automatically starts `case 1` then `case 2, case 3`. i dont know how to implement `mediaplayer.setOnCompletionListener` inside this public method

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

ListView lv;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
int position = 0;

}


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            position = pos;
           .....
           .....

}

public void shuffle1(MenuItem item){
        mediaPlayer.stop();

        if(position > 3){
            position = 0;

        }
        else if(position < 0){
            position = 3;
        }

        switch(position){

            case 0:
                mediaPlayer  = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.al098);
                break;
            case 1:
                mediaPlayer  = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.al099);
                break;
            case 2:
                mediaPlayer  = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.al100);
                break;
            case 3:
                mediaPlayer  = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.al101);
                break;
        }

        mediaPlayer.start();
}

EDIT: I did like this, but still no affect:


    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                if(position == 0){
                    position++;
                    mediaplayer.start();
                }else if (position ==1){
                    position++;
                    mediaplayer.start();
                }else if (position ==2){
                    position++;
                    mediaplayer.start();
                }else if (position ==3){
                    position++;
                    mediaplayer.start();
                }else if (position ==4){
                    mediaplayer.stop();
                return;     
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: inside `shuffle` method in if statement of position 3 use return. So that switch statement won't got called

Comment: Sorry, i need they play automatically, like after `case 0` automatically starts `case 1` then `case 2, case 3`. i dont know how to implement `mediaplayer.setOnCompletionListener` inside this public method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code:

```
public void shuffle1(MenuItem item){
        mediaPlayer.stop();

        switch(position){

            case 0:
                mediaPlayer  = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.al098);
                break;
            case 1:
                mediaPlayer  = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.al099);
                break;
            case 2:
                mediaPlayer  = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.al100);
                break;
            case 3:
                mediaPlayer  = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.al101);
                break;
        }
        position++;
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                if(position == 4){
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    return;
                } else {
                    shuffle1(item);
                }
            }
        });

        mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

**EDIT**

As per changes asked in the comments

```
public void shuffle1(final MenuItem item, int startPosition, boolean playNow){
        mediaPlayer.stop();

        int position = this.position;
        if(playNow){
            position = startPosition;
        }
        switch(position){

            case 0:
                mediaPlayer  = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.al098);
                break;
            case 1:
                mediaPlayer  = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.al099);
                break;
            case 2:
                mediaPlayer  = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.al100);
                break;
            case 3:
                mediaPlayer  = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.al101);
                break;
        }
        if(!playNow){
            this.position++;
        }        
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                if(this.position == 4){
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    return;
                } else {
                    shuffle1(item, this.position, false);
                }
            }
        });

        mediaPlayer.start();
}
```